# Is there anyway in gmail to select "All" but just within the "Everything else" section

Tags: gmail

I often have a lot of everything else emails and i want to select all.  is there a way to do that without selecting you starred or unread emails?

Answer (score 2):

A minus sign serves as [a not](http://support.google.com/mail/answer/8931?hl=en&ref_topic=1668965)

- To search for all messages in the inbox -> **label:inbox**
- To search for unread in the inbox -> **label:inbox is:unread**
- To search for unread messages without stars in the inbox-> **-is:starred label:inbox is:unread**

Answer (score 2):

It seems complicated at first, because "Everything Else" seems nebulous, but there are straightforward ways to handle it.

```
in:inbox -is:important -is:starred is:unread has:nouserlabels
```

Starred and Important are the two most common labels that differentiate from 'everything else'.

Unread is a common dimension – since this kind of query is usually needed to clear up space in an inbox that is consuming many GB of quota.

Excluding labels will ensure that nothing you have personally categorized will be affected.  That said, if you auto-label many things but want to delete most of them, you'll have a harder time to build a list of what you want and don't-want.... but at least it will be an organized approach!

Answer (score 1):

The search you want is for "Unread Everything Else"

```
-is:important label:inbox is:unread
```

or just "Everything Else"

```
-is:important label:inbox
```